# Question about Clob object in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, clob

In the previous versions of Hibernate, it had the static api Hibernate.createClob(String), which allowed to create Clob object from String.

Now that this is deprecated, what is the proper way to store String as Clob in Hibernate?

I am having trouble figuring out how the Persistence Object (POJO) will look like.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA @Lob annotation:

```
@Lob
public String getFullText() { return fullText; }
```

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I had created a blog about how to read an Oracle XMLType into Hibernate. A Clob will also need a similar approach. I had written the details at

http://rationalspring.wordpress.com